# How to update an object after changing its uv coordinates?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm creating a node for [Sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) which will apply custom UV map to an object. Pretty simple thing but after applying new UV coordinates to an object object it doesn't update the viewer somehow. Switching to *Edit Mode* works but I'm sure there is a better way.

The problem can be reproduced this way:

- Create a default plane and apply any material with a texture like this: 
  [image]
- then call the code for assigning new UV coordiantes:

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
new_uv = [(0.5, 0), (1, 0.5), (0.5, 1), (0, 0.5)]
obj.data.uv_layers['UVMap'].data.foreach_set("uv", [n for v in new_uv for n in v])
print('Done')
```

- However, the changes are only applied when switching to *Edit Mode*:
  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple fix - all you need to do is run the `update()` function on the object's mesh data: `obj.data.update()`

Depending on your intended use case, you may also need to run `bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph.update()` to update the dependency graph.